# Searchbox for google map is not showing at all

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

So I have a google map on my website with searchbox and all..
The problem is that the input is not displaying itself even though I didnt use any jquery to it.

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address-map">Enter your property name/property address to plot location</label>
      <input id="pac-input" class="form-control" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" style="border:3px solid #f5b9b9"/>
 </div>
 <div id="map"></div>
```

and the script:

```
 var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
 document.getElementById('pac-input'));

 var types = document.getElementById('type-selector')
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,option);
 autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

I am certain the TOP_LEFT is doing something to it and I need a workaround to display the input and still can search.
I did search for answers but sadly it made my map not appear at all even the input.

------edit-----

I guess I didn't made my question clear as I would like the input be on the upper part of the map where both are in different divs..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. How are you including the API? (are you including the places library?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway as I already solved my own question so all I did was to just commment out the position of the input and it would let my input be positioned up the map div.

```
//this line is commented out
//map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

[This is the layout that I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnYy9.png)